# ggseasonalplot for daily data is not working

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, ggplot2

I am new to R.
The daily data of a pump has been taken. The data is of two years and has the row of 742 numbers.

```
cw<-read.csv("RCW1.csv")

str(cw)

data.frame':    742 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ date       : Date, format: "2016-04-01" "2016-04-02" "2016-04-03" ...
 $ amp        : num  226 227 0 225 226 ...
 $ brg_de_tmp : num  38.1 38.1 39.6 41.6 41.5 ...
 $ brg_nde_tmp: num  78.6 79.1 72 79.9 80.4 ...
 $ kg         : num  2.07 2.07 0.06 2.29 2.28 2.3 2.11 2.1 2.11 2.11 ...
 $ level1     : num  8.45 8.46 8.69 8.67 8.43 8.6 8.39 8.5 8.46 8.65 ...
 $ level2     : num  8.44 8.46 8.67 8.65 8.42 8.59 8.38 8.48 8.46 8.63 ...
 $ mde_xvib   : num  1.15 1.35 0.28 1.05 1.15 1.06 1.25 1.25 1.25 1.25 ...
 $ mde_zvib   : num  1.37 1.57 0.4 1.18 1.13 1.38 1.28 1.57 1.3 1.5 ...
 $ rpm        : num  296.46 296.91 -4.76 297.09 297.91 ...
 $ mde_yvib   : num  2.09 2.38 0.34 2 1.82 2.24 2.17 2.56 1.9 2.27 ...
 $ m_nde_yvib : num  1.15 1.13 0.35 0.96 0.96 0.96 1.15 1.06 1.15 1.15 ...
 $ m_nde_zvib : num  1.53 1.63 0.27 1.33 1.43 1.4 1.76 1.63 1.79 1.71 ...
 $ permit     : chr  "#N/A" "#N/A" "CW Pump house: Motor stand" "#N/A" ...
```

## convert it into time series

```
cw_x <- xts(cw, order.by=as.Date(cw[,1], "%Y/%m/%d"))

cw_ts<-as.ts(cw_x)

> head(cw_ts)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 6 
Frequency = 1 
        date    amp brg_de_tmp brg_nde_tmp   kg level1 level2 mde_xvib mde_zvib    rpm mde_yvib
1 2016-04-01 226.05      38.06       78.61 2.07   8.45   8.44     1.15     1.37 296.46     2.09
2 2016-04-02 226.59      38.08       79.13 2.07   8.46   8.46     1.35     1.57 296.91     2.38
3 2016-04-03   0.00      39.57       71.96 0.06   8.69   8.67     0.28     0.40  -4.76     0.34
4 2016-04-04 225.01      41.57       79.91 2.29   8.67   8.65     1.05     1.18 297.09     2.00
5 2016-04-05 226.41      41.54       80.43 2.28   8.43   8.42     1.15     1.13 297.91     1.82
6 2016-04-06 225.65      41.08       79.89 2.30   8.60   8.59     1.06     1.38 297.55     2.24
  m_nde_yvib m_nde_zvib                     permit
1       1.15       1.53                       #N/A
2       1.13       1.63                       #N/A
3       0.35       0.27 CW Pump house: Motor stand
4       0.96       1.33                       #N/A
5       0.96       1.43                       #N/A
6       0.96       1.40                       #N/A
```

I have two questions.

Number 1:    How can I get "dates" in X-axis while plotting the following code.

```
autoplot(cw_ts[,2:5],facets = TRUE) + ylab("parameters")
```

[image: Autoplot graph]

See I am getting row number in X-axis, I want to change to dates.

Question number 2:    I am trying to get seasonal plot with following two codes as describes by Robjhyndman book "Forecasting: principle and practice"

```
ggseasonplot(cw_ts, year.labels=TRUE, year.labels.left=TRUE) +
ylab("") +
ggtitle("Seasonal plot: Pump parameter")
```

AND

```
ggseasonplot(cw_ts, polar=TRUE) +
ylab("") +
ggtitle("Polar seasonal plot: Pump parameter")
```

So how do i impute my time series into above code. While I am getting following error.

```
ggseasonplot(cw_ts, year.labels=TRUE, year.labels.left=TRUE) +
+   ylab("") +
+   ggtitle("Seasonal plot: Pump parameter")
Error in ggseasonplot(cw_ts, year.labels = TRUE, year.labels.left = TRUE) : 
  Data are not seasonal
```

AND

```
 ggseasonplot(cw_ts, polar=TRUE) +
+   ylab("") +
+   ggtitle("Polar seasonal plot: Pump parameter")
Error in ggseasonplot(cw_ts, polar = TRUE) : Data are not seasonal
>
```

Any suggestion will help me a lot. Thank You.

Comment: See https://otexts.org/fpp2/ts-objects.html

Comment: @RobHyndman, I got the answer for my first question. I can write the following code for that  [ p1 <- autoplot(cw_ts) +
  ylab("") + xlab("date")  ]   ..                                                                                                                                                                                                         Any suggestion for my second question. How could I will be able to interpret my daily data in to seasonal plot.

Comment: Turn the data into a ts object with the frequency equal to length of seasonal period, then ggseasonplot() will work.